# Binding `FXTask` message to `Label` without component coupling in TornadoFX

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

Good day. I was wondering if there is a convenient or streamlined way of binding `FXTask`'s `messageProperty` and `runningProperty` to `Label`'s `textProperty` and `visibleWhen` property accordingly without coupling `FXTask` and `Label` themselves?

For example in the sample app below, I'm binding `messageProperty` by coupling label's reference to a task, which introduces an extra `lateinit var statusLabel`. Similarly, I'm binding `runningProperty` by coupling task's reference to a label which introduces an extra `val task`.

```
class DummyView : View("Dummy View") {
    override val root = vbox {
        lateinit var statusLabel: Label

        val task = object : Task<Void>() {
            public override fun call(): Void? {
                Platform.runLater { statusLabel.textProperty().bind(messageProperty()) } // label coupling

                updateMessage("Initializing task...")
                (1..3).forEach {
                    Thread.sleep(1000)
                    updateMessage("Doing task: $it...")
                }

                Thread.sleep(1000)
                updateMessage("Task done")
                Thread.sleep(1000)
                return null
            }
        }

        button("Do task") {
            action {
                Thread(task).apply {// task coupling
                    isDaemon = true
                }.start()
            }
        }
        statusLabel = label("Status") {
            visibleWhen(task.runningProperty()) // task coupling
        }
    }
}

class DummyApp : App(DummyView::class)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `TaskStatus` object that can be passed into `runAsync`. This object has all the interesting properties of the task you're running. No need to subclass `Task` either :)

```
class DummyView : View("Dummy View") {
    val taskStatus = TaskStatus()

    override val root = vbox {
        button("Do task") {
            action {
                runAsync(taskStatus) {
                    updateMessage("Initializing task...")
                    (1..3).forEach {
                        Thread.sleep(1000)
                        updateMessage("Doing task: $it...")
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(1000)
                    updateMessage("Task done")
                    Thread.sleep(1000)
                }
            }
        }
        label(taskStatus.message) {
            visibleWhen(taskStatus.running)
        }
    }
}
```

You could even use the automatically available taskStatus simply by injecting it. If you don't pass a specific instance of TaskStatus to runAsync, you'll get the default instance. Therefor this also works: (Difference is TaskStatus is injected, and no instance of TaskStatus is passed to runAsync)

```
class DummyView : View("Dummy View") {
    val taskStatus: TaskStatus by inject()

    override val root = vbox {
        button("Do task") {
            action {
                runAsync {
                    updateMessage("Initializing task...")
                    (1..3).forEach {
                        Thread.sleep(1000)
                        updateMessage("Doing task: $it...")
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(1000)
                    updateMessage("Task done")
                    Thread.sleep(1000)
                }
            }
        }
        label(taskStatus.message) {
            visibleWhen(taskStatus.running)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. I have one more question: when is it preferred to create an instance of `TaskStatus` and when is it preferred to inject it? What are the pros and cons of each approach?

Comment: And how one might cancel the task, given there is no reference to it?

Comment: The injected `TaskStatus` is shared by every async job run in the same scope, so it's really convenient that way. If you need tighter control, or want to show the progress of multiple tasks in a ui simultaneously, you'd need to instantiate separate `TaskStatus` objects and pass them into each `runAsync` call.

Comment: To cancel a task, you could inject a ViewModel which could be accessed both by the task and the call site. You could also manually instantiate an object and pass it in. If you set a certain value in a property within that object, the task would know to cancel.