# updating label with progress of http post not working. IllegalStateException

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I am having trouble with binding a UI component to an observable that gets updated progress from a http post event. I get an IllegalStateException

As I understand it the issue is the bind update is not happening on the UI thread. The answers I have read say that I need to use runAsync and then specify a UI block to update the UI component, but I am at a loss for how to accomplish this.

```
// View class
private val controller: ZumController by inject()

item("_Upload") {
    isMnemonicParsing = true
    action {
       controller.uploadToServer()
    }
}

bottom = label() {
    useMaxWidth = true
    padding = Insets(5.0, 10.0, 5.0, 10.0)
    this.bind(controller.progress)
}

// Controller class
var progress = SimpleStringProperty("Select images to upload")

fun uploadToServer() {
    images.forEach{ p ->
        Fuel.upload("http://127.0.0.1:8089")
                .add {FileDataPart(File(p), name = "file")}
                .progress { readBytes, totalBytes ->
                    progress.value = (readBytes.toFloat() / totalBytes.toFloat() * 100).toString()}
     .response { _ -> }
    }
}
```

How would I go about making sure the UI is updated during the application thread when I need progress before function call (uploadToServer()) returns? Sorry if this has already been answered, I still don't get exactly what is happening here.

Comment: I think I might have finally found my answer. I see here that I can use updateMessage() to relay the progress and with that I can set my label to task status.message. Am I on the right track now??https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51428584/binding-fxtask-message-to-label-without-component-coupling-in-tornadofx

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem with the following changes. I pass the FXTask to function uploadToServer(). There I updateMessage() with the progress callback for the http POST request. I can't say its the best way but it works. feel free to update this answer with more clear and concise code

```
item("_Upload") {
    isMnemonicParsing = true
    action {
        runAsync {
            controller.uploadToServer(this)
        } ui {

        }
    }
}

fun uploadToServer(task: FXTask<*>) {
    images.forEach{ p ->
        Fuel.upload("http://127.0.0.1:8089")
                .add {FileDataPart(File(p), name = "file")}
                .progress { readBytes, totalBytes ->
                    val perComplete = readBytes.toFloat() / totalBytes.toFloat() * 100
                    task.updateMessage("Uploading $p %.2f".format(perComplete).plus("%"))
                }
                .response { _ -> }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TornadoFX has a built in `TaskStatus` object which has properties for the progress of the task. You can bind one or more of the properties in the `TaskStatus` object to any UI element, and simply call `updateProgress` from within your controller function. You don't even need to pass in the `TaskStatus` object, as the default instance will be used if you don't.

There are a few test appa within the framework that does this:

https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx/blob/master/src/test/kotlin/tornadofx/testapps/AsyncProgressApp.kt
https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx/blob/master/src/test/kotlin/tornadofx/testapps/TaskStatusTest.kt

That said, a quick and dirty solution for updating the UI from any other thread is simply wrapping the UI manipulation code inside `runLater {}`. This will work equally well for just updating a label for example.